# Is there a way to specify references in code?

Tags: c#, .net

Given a small C# program, *not* a Visual Studio project, just a small program entirely contained in a single file `foo.cs`, to be compiled with the command line compiler:

```
csc foo.cs
```

The program uses big integers. It contains the appropriate directive `using System.Numerics;`. However, this does not suffice by itself. The compiler also requires an assembly reference:

```
csc -r:System.Numerics.dll foo.cs
```

In practice, that means some form of build script must be supplied, doubling the number of files required to distribute the small program.

Is there any way of specifying that reference, within the C# code itself?

Comment: To compile the dot net code you need some dot net SDK on the computer.  This SDK should contain the library you need to refer to.  Are you looking to merge the compile command into the same file as the source code?  You might be able to do that with a powershell script.  Something like   type "Blah blah code" > afile.cs; compile afile.cs;  but I am not sure it is worth it.

Comment: If you are in the habit of distributing small programs as .cs files (and not as compiled programs) I'm guessing you may be very interested in [c# scripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt614271.aspx), which allows you to supply references within the file using the `#r` directive.

Comment: If you just want to use this for small spikes / code sharing at your company ... we're using LINQPad for this, it even comes with NuGet support.